# find all that are nil in the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a Post and a User.
Post has_many users and a user belongs_to a post.
I need a find that will find all the Posts that dont have any users like the following:

```
Post.first.users
 => []
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
Post.where("id not in (select post_id from users)")
```

Comment: If the subquery contains a nil, nothing will be returned and you might want to use `NOT EXISTS` instead, like I needed to in my particular case.  [Further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists).

Comment: Simple and elegant...

Answer (score 22):

Learned this one just today:

```
Post.eager_load(:users).merge(User.where(id: nil))
```

Works with Rails 4+ at least.

Update:

In Rails 5+, you can use `left_joins` instead:

```
Post.left_joins(:users).merge(User.where(id: nil))
```

Comment: Cool solution. It actually works if the relation is not in the default scope (in our case "soft-deleted").

Answer (score 2):

If you need something that is fast, employ a SQL statement like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM posts p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON p.id = u.post_id 
WHERE u.id IS null
```

Answer (score 2):

something like that:

```
p = Post.arel_table
u = User.arel_table

posts = Post.find_by_sql(p.join(u).on(p[:user_id].eq(u[:p_id])).where(u[:id].eq(nil)).to_sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is tagged as Rails 3, but if you are using Rails 4, I've been doing it like this.

```
Post.where.not(user_id: User.pluck(:id))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Post.first.users.empty?` should be sufficient if users returns an array.

If you want to check for each post you could do

```
Post.each do |p|
  if p.users.empty?
    do whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: i need to find all the Posts...not just the first

Comment: so i need something like Post.all(:include => :users, :conditions => "users = ?", nil)

Comment: `Post.each do |p| if p.users == nil do whatever end end`

Answer (score 1):

i guess a sql with in can cause performance problems if database table has many rows. careful with that

Comment: Right. Start with the most readable code, secure it with tests, and then you may start to optimize the performance. Without tests, you risk that you "optimize away" some records by accident. And always measure the real performance: optimized version is not always the fastest.