# find all that are nil in the association in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, include

Here I've got a 1-to-many relationship between `Property` and `Users`:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
end
```

How could I get all the properties which do not belong to any user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find all that are nil in the association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947843/find-all-that-are-nil-in-the-association)

Comment: See my answer below. You will get what you want. I have tested already.

Answer (score 10):

To get all properties that have no user, try this:

```
Property.includes(:users).where(users: { property_id: nil })
```

Answer (score 4):

One more approach would be to write some `SQL`:

```
Property.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.property_id = properties.id").
where('users.id IS NULL').
uniq
```

The code above is being translated to the following pure `SQL` query to the database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT properties.* FROM properties 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users on users.property_id = properties.id 
WHERE users.id IS NULL;
```

`LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all rows from the left table (`properties`), with the matching rows in the right table (`users`). The result is `NULL` in the right side when there is no match. Afterwards `WHERE` keyword filters results by a condition that we're intrested in those rows which have `NULL` on the right side only.

[image: Left outer join with WHERE NULL]

Reference: [SQL LEFT JOIN Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: I prefer this way over `NOT IN` way

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this too:

```
Property.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(property_id) FROM users)')
```

Another option would be:

```
Property.where("(select count(*) from users where property_id = properties.id) = 0")
```

You can always check which is more efficient according to you application by checking the time take to execute the queries and choose an option accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Also You can write scope based on this query just for easy use.

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  scope :incomplete, -> { joins(:users).where("property.user_id is null") }
end
```

Then, You can call this scope like this: `Property.incomplete`

Comment: `joins(:users)` makes `INNER JOIN` here, which means you gonna get a blank result set. you should use `LEFT JOIN` to get desired behaviour.

Comment: True. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
Property.where.not(:id=>User.where.not(:property_id=>nil).pluck(:property_id))
```

or

```
 Property.where.not(:id=>User.where.not(:property_id=>nil).pluck("DISTINCT property_id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
@users= User.includes(:properties).where(properties: { property_id: nil })
```

Comment: this seems to return users without properties (which is opposite to what topic starter wants)